# Wrong architecture for both 32 and 64 bit

Tags: software-installation, software-center, 64-bit, 32-bit, arm64

I have a strange problem, trying to install software from software center or download and receive the same issue. If I choose 64 bit software, "wrong architecture" if I choose 32 bit software, "wrong architecture".

I ran `uname -a` and this was the response:

> Linux firefly 4.4.114 #62 SMP Wed Apr 4 11:10:34 HKT 2018 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

This is Ubuntu 16.04 on a Libre Computer single board, supposed to be 64 bit system.

Any help or ideas?

Comment: What CPU model do you have(`lscpu` output will be useful)? Is it ARM or x86?

Comment: I should've done more research before posting. I discovered it is an ARM system and that is the problem with software connection.

Comment: I guess that leads to a follow on question. What is a good source for software that works on an ARM system?

Answer (score 1):

If Ubuntu was shipped pre-installed on your SBC - it should have correct Ubuntu-repositories.

You should check your software sources (repositories) and ensure that you have only ARM-related lines in */etc/apt/sources.list* and files in */etc/apt/sources.list.d/* directory.
Usually the repository URL is `http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports` .

You can search https://packages.ubuntu.com for arm64 packages.